# PHP: Converting Complex Multidimensional Array to a Simple Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to convert the array below to something simpler so it is easier to understand. There is more than one order by the way mates I just show the first one because it is already too long.

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [no] => 1
    [FL] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
          (
              [val] => ORDERID
              [content] => 2244668800
          )
        [1] => Array
          (
              [val] => Account Name
              [content] => John Doe
          )
        [3] => Array
          (
            [val] => Product Details
            [product] => Array
              (
                [0] => Array
                  (
                    [no] => 1
                    [FL] => Array
                      (
                        [0] => Array
                          (
                            [val] => Product Id
                            [content] => 1122334455
                          )
                        [1] => Array
                          (
                            [val] => Product Name
                            [content] => Samsung Monitor
                          )
                      )
                  )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                      [no] => 2
                      [FL] => Array
                        (
                          [0] => Array
                            (
                              [val] => Product Id
                              [content] => 1122334456
                            )
                          [1] => Array
                            (
                              [val] => Product Name
                              [content] => Fractal Case
                            )
                        )

                    )
              )
          )
      )
  )
)
```

What I would like it to be is something like this.

```
[0] => Array(
  'orderid' => '2244668800',
  'accountname' => 'John Doe',
  'monitorproductid' => '1122334455',
  'monitor' => 'Samsung Monitor',
  'caseproductid' => '1122334456',
  'case' => 'Fractal Case'
)
```

I have no problem getting the `orderid` and `accountname` but I am honestly having problems with the `monitorproductid`, `monitor`, `caseproductid`, `case`

I am using a foreach to get the `orderid` and `accountname` like this.

```
$order = $jsonarray; //Array Shown Above

//Init Simple Array
$simplearray = array();

foreach ( $order['FL'] as $key => $val ) {
 //Get Account Name
 if (  $val['val'] == 'Account Name'  ) {
  $accountname = $val['content'];
 }

 //Get Order ID
 if (  $val['val'] == 'ORDERID'  ) {
  $orderid = $val['content'];
 }

 //Generate Simple Array
 $simplearray[] = array(
                   'accountname' => $accountname,
                   'orderid' => $orderid,
                   'monitorproductid' => '', //Need to Figure Out This
                   'monitor' => '', //Need to Figure Out This
                   'caseproductid' => '', //Need to Figure Out This
                   'case' => '' //Need to Figure Out This
                  );
}
```

Thank you in advance mates. I am new to the multidimensional array. I have looked in various sites but can't find a similar case to mine.

Comment: how are you creating your arrays? I think that's the code we'll want to see... think your code is creating a not-so-logical array

Comment: It is a response from a particular CRM mate. It is a JSON converted to PHP using `json_decode`. It is annoying mate but I kind of like the challenge.

Comment: I'd change CRM hahaha that return data shouldn't be so split, how is the CRM working? Logically, it should just return got data in single-level array (or multi of singles) - erm no worries, if it's the CRM then it's out of your control how the initial array comes back. Best bet maybe is create a new array inside the foreach loop and just specify key names

Comment: Mate, do you think you can update my foreach loop to show what you mean. I got the idea but I cannot seem to make it work properly. Basically I added a new `foreach` loop for the `Product Details` part but I cannot figure out how to get the value.

Comment: The `product` array contains multiple products - so do you want to create an entry in your new array as shown for each product? So there would eventually be several items with the same order id and account name?

Comment: Hi, the `accountname` is always unique on each main key and I have no issue adding it to the new `$simplearray`. As for the `products`, yes that is my intention to add the products in the simple array. So each product will add two new key value pair in the simple array which are their id and their value.